# Adding an offset for each iteration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a string in my ASP.NET MVC5 project which contains parent elements of the current directory (Active Directory TreeView, using Organizational Units). What I am trying to achieve is to have an offset for each element you iterate through, so then you can see parent elements and the visuals are nice, something like this :

```
Element 1
   Element 1.1
      SubElements(Current) //These are not concerned by my question
      MoreSubs
      etc...
```

I use razor views, and I have tried using methods `PadLeft` and `String.Format` but the result is not any good and I can't find a solution that will make for some nice results. I've also noticed that using `PadLeft` I cannot use spaces as characters, hence it does not really fit my needs. And I couldn't manage to make `String.Format` work. Here is what I have for now:

```
string myString = "OU=DR,OU=MR,OU=GTC,"
int offset = 5;
string[] units = myString.Split(',');
foreach (var unit in units)
{
    if(unit.Equals("")|| unit.Equals(" ")){
        continue;
    }
    @unit.PadLeft(offset, '-')<br/>
    //String.Format("{0,"+offset+"}",unit); couldn't make this work
    offset += 5;
}
```

Nevermind the fact that my Organizational Units iterate upside down, for now I just want this offset (probably something really easy I cannot achieve :( ). Here this gives this kind of visual:

```
Elements 1
Element 1.1 //No padding here, why?
---Elements 1.2
    SubElements
```

Comment: Why are you tying to so this with `PadLeft()`. Assuming your displaying this in a view, use css to style the elements with padding or margins.

Comment: Yes but how to distinguish depth? Say 1 has an offset of 0 then 1.1 offset of 5px then 1.2 is 10px? But I can't know how deep it can go

Comment: Ah I think I get what your saying, I will try

Comment: Well you must know your structure (how else could you be adding the correct `PadLeft()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, I read that styling should mostly be done in stylesheets, so I guess here I have to do it directly in my view. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it this way, not sure if it's really the best way but it works!

```
string myString = "OU=DR,OU=MR,OU=GTC,";
string offSet = "5px";
string[] units = myString.Split(',');
foreach (var unit in units)
{
    if (unit.Equals("") || unit.Equals(" ")) {
        continue;
    }
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
    <b id="orgUnit" style="padding-left:@offSet">@unit</b> <br/>
    offSet = offSet.Replace("px", "");
    int offToInt = int.Parse(offSet);
    offToInt += 10;
    offSet = offToInt.ToString()+"px";
}
```